# Opening a url inside a popup element (get new title and address bar)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to create something like this:

```
<a href="post/23">post 23</a>
```

once a user click on this element
I want to fadein a popup div and load page post/23 html to it.
I want to title and address bar to change accrodingly to the new post page title and address bar.
Once I close the popup div, I want the title and address bad to be changed back.

I am sorry I don't have any code for you guys, I am looking for this for quite some time, and unable to find anything certain.

my best guess was using 
http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html

can someone with experience performing something similar help me please?

Comment: The link you supplied shows step by step how to implement the add-in, including examples, and different options. I think you should just read it, and try yourself. If you then have a problem, come ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I figured how to do it myself using history.js
this is how I did it:

```
var urlPath;
$('.post-image').on('click',function(){
    urlPath = $(this).attr('href');
    History.pushState({ action: 'show_popup' } , 'POST TITLE', urlPath);
    return false;
});

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() {
    var State = History.getState();
    if(State.data.action == "show_popup"){
        //show dimmer
        $("#lightbox").load(urlPath, function() {
            //show content
        });
    }else{
        // hide popup
    }
});
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
// hiding popup if dimmer is clicked
    if ((!$(event.target).closest('.post-info').length && !$(event.target).closest('.post-user').length))  {
        History.back();
    }
});`
```

Answer (score 2):

1.
Include jQueryUI Dialog JS :

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

2.
Append class, data-title attribute to your a link elemenets.
HTML:

```
<a class="alink" href="post/23" data-title="post23" >post 23</a>
<a class="alink" href="post/24" data-title="post24" >post 24</a>
```

3.
Javascript:

```
$(".alink").click(function () {
        var dialog = $('<div title="' + $(this).attr('data-title') + '"></div>').dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         hide: 'fade',
         show: 'fade',
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('href'),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $(dialog).html(html);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $(dialog).remove();
                        alert("Some Error MSG");
                    }
                });
            },
            close: function () {
                $(dialog).remove();
            },
            resizable: false,
            width: 500,
            modal: true
        });
    });
```

Now, Eachtime when you click on your link, a popup will open with fade effect, the title of dialog will come from your data-title attribute, and the dialog will get html from your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:-

In the first html page, you'll have a link/button to open the popup, so first thing is we can't open the popup with bootstrap's attributes, because in that case can't catch the event when the modal will be opened or closed. So we'll add a click event. And in the modal, we'll have a iframe to open a separate page. So the page will be:-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Bootstrap 3.1.0 - Modal Demo</h2>

        <div class="row text-center">
            <h3>The Basic Modal</h3>

        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-btn-name="basic_modal" data-src="demo.html">Click to open Modal</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="basicModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <iframe id="frame" src=""></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now we'll have another html file, that'll be opened in the popup, and we'll fire an event to the parent window when the iframe will be loaded, so that we can get the title of the iframe.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script>
        function onLoad(){
            var event = new parent.CustomEvent('print:page:loaded', {detail : window});
            parent.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div>TODO write content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now in the javascript we'll listen to the event fired by the iframe and change the window title depending on it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var originalTitle,originalUrl;
$('[data-btn-name="basic_modal"]').click(function(evt){
    if($('#basicModal').hasClass('in')){
        window.document.title = originalTitle;     
        window.history.pushState('test', originalTitle, originalUrl);
    }else{
        $('#frame').attr('src',$(evt.currentTarget).attr('data-src'));
        window.removeEventListener('print:page:loaded',function(){},false);
        window.addEventListener('print:page:loaded', function(e){
            originalTitle = window.document.title;
            originalUrl = window.location.href;
            window.document.title = e.detail.document.title; 
            window.history.pushState('test', e.detail.document.title, $(evt.currentTarget).attr('data-src'));
        })
    }
    $('#basicModal').toggleClass('in');
});
})
```